# Codeigniter Download Helper corrupts .7z and .rar files help or alternative solutions?

Tags: php, codeigniter, helper

I am using Codeigniter's Download helper for "easy" downloading.

```
    $this->load->helper('download');
    $file = //get_file_name_from_db
    $data = file_get_contents( upload_path . $file);
    force_download($file, $data);
```

The problem that I have is that any .zip is downloading correctly while .7z and .rar are not. However when I check the uploaded files to see it they are corrupted or not they are fine (via FTP or in local by simply checking the folders).

To add to the confusion if a file is really small (like 5kb or so) then none of the types (7z and rar) will be corrupted.

For the reference here is the mime types I use in mime.php (that both upload and download helper use)

```
'zip'   =>  array('application/x-zip', 'application/zip', 'application/x-zip-compressed'),
'7z'    =>     array('application/x-7z-compressed','application/x-7z',      'application/7z', 'application/force-download', 'application/octet-stream'),
'rar'   =>  array('application/x-rar-compressed','application/x-rar', 'application/rar', 'application/octet-stream')
```

THe problem might be at two points, either the mime types (which it probably isn't since as noted, on very small file sizes it works). Or the file_get_contents() and the header("Content-Length: ".strlen($data)); which might not be so since regardless of size .zip will always download correctly.

Or might it be a sever config problem? I tested it both on a host and at localhost and they behave the same.

So does anybody knows what the problem is or can they suggest an alternative download script or method I should use?

UPDATE:
I uploaded a 7z file on the host with the size of 1.8 MB and when downloaded the file wasn't corrupted... I am having harder and harder time understanding what is the problem.

UPDATE:

Found the answer it was a value that was on top of the file form the some connected method where I have echoed a value in order to check it some time ago.

For more here:
[What causes downloaded files to become corrupt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16446366/what-causes-downloaded-files-to-become-corrupt)

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is inbuild library in PHP for generating 7z or rar files like zip/gzip. You might need to use external library for this if it is there.