# What causes downloaded files to become corrupt?

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

I am currently stugling to understand just what is wrong with my app.

As I was unable to find a solution (more about that here: [Codeigniter Download Helper corrupts .7z and .rar files help or alternative solutions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16440904/codeigniter-download-helper-corrupts-7z-and-rar-files-help-or-alternative-solu)) I decided to take a different approach.

So the question is what causes downloaded files via the HTML request (if I said that right) to become corrupt even when they are not corrupted when downloaded via FTP. And a follow up is, what causes a specific type of extension to become corrupt. Since I can download zip files fine but 7z and rar files get corrupted.

This is the header list that codeiniter's download helper uses:

```
        header('Content-Type: "'.$mime.'"');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Pragma: no-cache');
        header("Content-Length: ".strlen($data));
```

The helper uses file_get_contents() in order to determine content-length and send. I tried to use filesize() and to send a file via readfile() but the result was the same.

I also tried different mimes, from the all inclusive application/octet-stream to the spefic ones depending on the type (application/x-7z-compressed etc) but it had little effect.

So at this point I have no idea what causes some extensions to work while others do not.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Is there some php, or apache or any tweak, property I can use to change this?

EDIT:

I noticed that for some reason when I open a file there is a added number that represents an ID of the download i have no idea how it got here or how to stop it, but this have put me on the right track. Thanks so very much, i will update this one as I progress.

Also how to prevent php to append something on top of my file?

EDIT:

FOUND IT!

It was an obscure echo that I simply didn't see, I was just so tired. But now that it is gone everything works fine. I've spend around hours truing to find out what was wrong, I am pissed of at myself, but right now I am glat it is over. Thanks so very much helping me find the problem :)

Comment: If you get a file that is downloaded that is corrupt, the first thing you should do is just open it in a text editor. Most of the time I find that there was a php error that was echo'd out at the top of the file. You can often even delete the error and open the file afterwards.

Comment: What browser are you downloading from? I have a full download snippet that has served me very well.

Comment: load the file into a text/hex editor, look for obvious php warnings/errors that may have been output before the file data started. do a byte-wise comparison of the original and downloaded files to see WHERE the difference(s) is/are. and while this isn't the cause of your problem, mime content-type doesn't need quoting. e.g. `Content-type: image/jpeg` is fine. `"image/jpeg"` would be "wrong".

Comment: Thank you for the response. I edited the first post in order to reflect on the advices.

Comment: This is obviously not related to your problem since you've identified the extra character's origin, but I figured I'd add it in as just something to watch out for. In download scripts it's also very important that you do not have any characters before or after your php tag (this includes newlines).

Comment: Is your controller spitting anything out? Scan the controller to see if you don't have any echo statements. Also for the content length may want to try `filesize()` instead of `strlen()`

Comment: I am still in the process of discovering a problem so your input is much valued.